# Android switch views after TimerTask condition

Tags: android, android-asynctask, timertask, ui-thread

I want to build a few conditions to kick a user out of an activity after X amount of time.

I get the general idea:

- store the current time in milliseconds , from a calendar object in milliseconds
- determine how long I want the user to be in the activity
- add the how long + stored current time to determine what calendar time in milliseconds to boot close that activity
- compare the kickout time to the present time in milliseconds

for the last step I found that the best "time listener" I could find was TimerTask, implemented as such:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success){

      kickout.schedule(new KickoutTask(), 5000);

}

class KickoutTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();

            replaceRootView(getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("myPreviousActivity", new
                Intent(this, myPreviousActivity.class)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView());

        Looper.loop();

    }
}
```

This is at the final part of an AsyncTask, the counting and "time listening" actually works, but when it comes to replace the view in the `run()` method, the app crashes with

`"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."`

I understand the concept but I don't understand how else to get out of this activity upon resolution of the counting in the `schedule` function. Also I need to "replace" the view instead of just using "finish()" for this activity because of some refreshing that needs to take place.

I would like to use another simple AsyncTask, but the `schedule` function requires a TimerTask

Insight Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should do this task in [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Second you need to use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to update views from other thread.

Refer this tutorial on `Handler` and `AsyncTask`:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I will use Handler? I was getting crashes with that being called from the run() method too. CountDownTimer looks pretty interesting. I will be implementing conditions for onPause and onResume, does CountDownTimer assist with this, being an Android function?

Comment: I have edited the answer for handler and yes you can use CountDownTimer from onResume() and onPause().